# close active connection on linux base server

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

well, i got situation here.

i have some application that listen to some server data transaction (linux based) to get the data and send it to database on another server (windows).

the application is unstable, and it may crash if found some null variable. i cannot fix the application since it's not mine and use language that im not capable of (and i have no time since it's on production state).

what im asking for are,

> how can i close the connection between my application and server from the server?

so i can re-run the application, since it give error "multi-session not supported".

situation are,

1. i have checked with netstat, that my application connection state
   are ESTABLISHED with right IP.
2. i have root permission.
3. i may not restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

netstat -tulp|grep ESTABLISHED get the connection's pid. then kill 9 pid.